# Convert any url in class.phpmailer.php

Tags: php, javascript, html, email, phpmailer

After 3 weeks searching, I have found this great answers >>> [How to replace plain URLs with links?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37684/how-to-replace-plain-urls-with-links)

but I don't know how to use this with phpmailer..

I am using an html form to send information to email. Some email service can't see url as a link. What i need to do, I am newbie in phpmailer.

I hope this site is the best place to seek the answer. Thanks you very much.

Comment: For seeking perhaps. For asking I'd say less, because your question right now tells what you look for however it does not say what your specific programming problem is. You might be lucky to get answers, but rest assured that the answers will be of equal quality like the question.

Answer (score 0):

Extend phpmailer with a class you make

```
<?php

CLASS url_free_phpmailer EXTENDS phpmailer {

   /**
    * Replaces urls before sending
    *
    */
   public function Send() {
      $this->Body = replace_urls($this->Body);
      return call_user_func_array('parent::'.__FUNCTION__, func_get_args());
   }


}
```

or just

```
<?php

require("class.phpmailer.php");

$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->From     = "from@example.com";
$mail->AddAddress("myfriend@example.net");

$mail->Subject  = "First PHPMailer Message";

# replace urls before setting
$mail->Body     = replace_urls($body);

$mail->WordWrap = 50;

if(!$mail->Send()) {
  echo 'Message was not sent.';
  echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
  echo 'Message has been sent.';
}
?>
```